# Node Stream Ending: Write after end

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

[image]

There is the error i am facing when i am sending the input to the child-process written in python. 
When i send the data for first time it gives output but with the second input i send me error. Hint that the pipe to covers is ended just after the first output i receive.
Can you help me.

here is the node code.

```
var bodyParse = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParse.urlencoded({extended: false});
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var py    = spawn('python', ['dialogue_management_model.py'])
module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    var typed = (JSON.stringify(req.body).substring(2, JSON.stringify(req.body).indexOf(":") - 1));
    console.log(typed)
    module.exports.typed = typed
    var data = typed;
    dataString = '';
    // Handling the Input data from the Front End With the Post request.

    // taking computed/operated data from the python file
    py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    dataString += data.toString();
    });

    // Simply logging it to the Console
    py.stdout.on('end', function(){
        console.log(dataString);
        res.send(dataString);
    }); 

    // python doesn't understand the data without string format
    py.stdin.write(data);
    py.stdin.end();

})

}
```

Just Server is started in other file and is passing full control to here and from here i am calling python code to take input do computation and pass me the result.

Comment: Try older version of npm => npm i -g npm@5.6.0                                                                          Read this post : https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19989

Comment: I have done trying with that. Still It didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ending the input stream entirely after the first call. Move `var py = spawn('python', ['dialogue_management_model.py'])` into the post request handler, so each request will spawn a child process, write the data, end the input stream, wait for a response, and return a result when the output stream ends.

This gives you the added benefit of making it more thread safe.  That is to say, if you have two requests come in at the same time, both will end up adding listeners for `py.stdout.on('data', ...`, resulting in both getting a mixture of output. Also I'm fairly certain `py.stdout.on('end',` would only trigger for once, so any request that comes in after the stdout.end callback runs from the first request(s) would hang until they timeout.

---

Also, unrelated to your question, but when you do:

`var typed = (JSON.stringify(req.body).substring(2, JSON.stringify(req.body).indexOf(":") - 1))`

you should assign the `JSON.stringify()` to a variable so you don't have to run it twice.

ie. `var payload = JSON.stringify(req.body); var typed = (payload.substring(2, payload.indexOf(":") - 1))`

But even then, if you just need the first key you can do `Object.keys(req.body)[0]` rather than converting the object to a string and parsing the string.